# How to refresh datagridview reading from shared database automatically?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

I have a shared MS-access database on a network and devices connected to this database, I want to update datagridview of all users' devices when any user insert new record .

Answer (score 1):

use a timer and backgroundworker to fetch data from shared database and bind the datagridview.